# Jest manual mocking works only for the first function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I've mocked a custom XHR wrapper that I've written (**utils/xhr.js**) using Jest manual mocking feature and the issue that I'm having is that **only the first XHR call is tracked**:

### utils/xhr.js

```
let xhr = {
    get: function(params) { /* XHR get implementation */ }
    post: function(params) { /* XHR post implementation */ }
};

export default xhr;
```

### utils/__mocks__/xhr.js - the mock implementation

```
let xhr = jest.genMockFromModule('./../xhr');

module.exports = xhr;
```

### Dashboard.api.js - the XHR calls for the dashboard component

```
// ...

getTrendingEntities: (days, maxItems) => {

    return xhr.get({url: '/api/aggregator/riskEntities/' +  days + '/' + maxItems})
        .then((response) => {
            companyIds = parseCompanies(response.body);

            return xhr.post({
                url: '/api/entities/specific-companies',
                data: companyIds
            });

        }).then((response) => {
            let companies = parseCompaniesData(response.body);

            return Promise.resolve(companies);
        });
}

// ...
```

### TrendingEntitiesPod.jsx - the React component that uses Dashboard.api.js

```
class TrendingEntitiesPod extends React.Component {

    // ...

    componentWillMount() {
        this.loadData(this.props.days)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.days != nextProps.days) {
            this.loadData(nextProps.days);
        }
    }

    loadData(days) {
        this.setState({loading: true});

        api.getTrendingEntities(days, DASHBOARD_PODS_ENTRIES_NUMBER)
            .then((companies) => {
                this.setState({
                    companies: companies,
                    loading:   false
                });
            });
    }

    render() { // ... }

}
```

### StartPage.TrendingEntitiesPod.spec.js - the test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import xhr from './../../../utils/xhr';
jest.mock('./../../../utils/xhr');

import TrendingEntitiesPod from './../Dashboard/components/TrendingEntitiesPod/TrendingEntitiesPod.jsx';

describe('StartPage.TrendingEntitiesPod:', () => {

    let wrapper = null;

    beforeAll(() => {
        xhr.get.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntities}));
        xhr.post.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntitiesData}));
        xhr.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntityPestleData}));

        wrapper = mount(<TrendingEntitiesPod days={30} />);

    });

    test('...stubbing works', () => {
        expect(xhr.get.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
        expect(xhr.post.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // returns false - why??
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to deal with this issue, as it seems that Jest doesn't play well when doing setTimeout() all the time, is to not test the component's state after all initial requests have done. You can test the individual methods that do the XHR requests (and data parsing logic/component state change). E.g.:

### AirlineCompanies.jsx

```
class AirlineCompanies extends React.Component {

    // ...

    loadData(numberOfCompanies) {
        this.setState({loading: true});

        return api.getAirlineCompanies(numberOfCompanies)
            .then((companies) => {
                this.setState({
                companies: companies,
                loading:   false
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            utils.logError(error, 'AirlineCompanies.loadData():');
            this.setState({loading: false});
        });
    }

    // ...

}
```

### AirlineCompanies.spec.js

```
let component = mount(<AirlineCompanies />).instance();
let airlineCompaniesData = [ /*... mock companies data ...*/ ];

it('...should have the state changed and eight AirlineCompany components after data is loaded', (done) => {
    xhr.get.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({body: airlineCompaniesData}));

    component.loadData(30).then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state('companies')).toEqual(airlineCompaniesData);
        expect(wrapper.find(AirlineCompany).length).toBe(8);
        done();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mounting with Enzyme a component that does multiple AJAX calls and multiple state changes, in the components' first lifecycle phases, **makes the unit tests run first** and afterwards the state changes are reflected.

This is due to the asynchronous nature of the AJAX and setState() calls.

A fix that I found for this is to add a **done** callback in the **beforeAll** block which finishes on **setTimeout(done, 0)**:

```
beforeAll((done) => {
    xhr.get.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntities}));
    xhr.post.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntitiesData}));
    xhr.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({body: trendingEntityPestleData}));

    wrapper = mount(<TrendingEntitiesPod days={30} />);

    // Delay the execution of tests, at the end, after the component
    // has been mounted, all XHR, setState and render calls are done.
    setTimeout(done, 0);
});
```